# Android Invalidate() method

Tags: android

I have developed a custom view which loads Sudoku board along with some pre -filled squares with numbers. User will have to fill empty squares with numbers such that it do not violate Sudoku rules. Now , i want to insure that , users can differentiate between pre-filled squares and squares which users have filled . This can be achieved by

a) Different Background color for the empty squares 
b) Different text colors for the numbers , given by user.

I am calling Invalidate() method with , when user makes an input so that squares can be redrawn.

Can you please suggest how i can code in onDraw() method to differentiate user's input from pre-filled numbers  .

Comment: Make the changed tiles appear **pressed**.

Comment: could you please share one sample algorithm to implement this.

Comment: You could simply use a StateList selector (it's all xml), without the need for custom drawing.